# How to prevent displaying True/False in column when using Image?

Tags: objectlistview

I would like to have an image in column for boolean type. To specify column properties, I use OLVColumn attribute and there I specify `ImageAspectName`.

```
[OLVColumn("UseK", DisplayIndex = 4, ImageAspectName = "ImageForUseK", CheckBoxes = false, Width = 40)]
public bool UseK
{
    get { return useK; }
    set
    {
        if (useK == value) return;
        useK = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("UseK");
    }
}
protected bool useK = true;

public string ImageForUseK()
{
    return "success";
}
```

This works fine and displaying image in column, but also displaying literal "True" next to image.

[image]

How can I avoid displaying string value of boolean property, while still using `ImageAspectName`?

Answer (score 0):

You could set AspectToStringFormat to a space.